# How to use backreferences beyond 9 in a PostgreSQL regular expression?

Tags: regex, postgresql

The following regex simply extracts a part of the matched text using the backreferencing numbers:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABCDEFGHIJ','(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)','\2');
B
```

But how to backreference beyond the ninth matched substring?

The following won't work (returns the first match + 0), neither will the use of $10 or ${10}:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABCDEFGHIJ','(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)','\10')
A0
```

Note: this example was simplified for clarity, and would of course not necessitate going beyond backreference 9.

Comment: No, it just plainly returns \g<10>

Comment: Search postgress about this. I know its just an example, but in reality, you would only need one capture group for this.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html), you use `\n` where `n` is 1-9 or `\&` to include the whole match.  So it isn't supported.  However, you maybe able to write a more complicated query using `regexp_split_to_array()` or `regexp_split_to_table()`.

Comment: I don't know if it supports non-capture form, but if it does, it should be used to free up a capture buffer. An alternative is to capture a larger sub-block then post process that using another expression. Should that not be enough, its big trouble.

Comment: Hey, what happens when you put `\111` as a replacement?

Comment: Well, how can you insert an octal code for a character then? Not interpolated for that? Oh, its probably a different type of escape for that.

Comment: Does Postgre support **named groups**? You would reference to group by name, not by 10+ number.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment and in @p.s.w.g's answer, according to [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html) this isn't possible.

However, there are some other RegEx functions that may help.  If you can update your question with a real world problem, I can help more specifically.  But here is an example that solves your initial question using `regexp_matches()`.

```
SELECT matches[10]
FROM regexp_matches('ABCDEFGHIJ', '(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)') AS matches;

 matches 
---------
 J
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-BACKREF-TABLE), back references greater than 9 are supported within the pattern string:

> `\mnn` (where `m` is a nonzero digit, and `nn` is some more digits, and the decimal value `mnn` is not greater than the number of closing capturing parentheses seen so far) a back reference to the `mnn`'th subexpression

However, it appears they are not supported in [replacement strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in `regexp_replace`:

> The `replacement` string can contain `\n`, where `n` is 1 through 9, to indicate that the source substring matching the `n`'th parenthesized subexpression of the pattern should be inserted …

Answer (score 0):

I would **prefer** the **`regexp_matches(...)` approach** mentioned by *@Sam* **in general**, but created a nice **`regexp_replace2(...)`**, pure sql, wrapper function **supporting back references > 9** here: [postgres-utils](https://bitbucket.org/andi1234/postgres-utils)

Comment: Your link gives message "repository not found" => do you still have this available somewhere else?